# Compare Year part of Date field in AWS CloudSearch Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Being new to AWS CloudSearch, got stuck on the following issue -
I need to get all the records from CloudSearch domain, which have same year (date field) passed with search query.

For example -

Like we do in the SQL SERVER -

```
Year(01/03/2020) -> Output - 2020
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for adding `C#` tag here? Do you want year from date in `C#`?

Comment: It just we are interacting with AWS Domain using C#

Comment: then, Do you want to get year from datetime in C#?